# Automated logon program

Tags: automation

I have an xp machine... which runs a program... that likes to lock up. Using a computer monitoring program we can now tell that it's locked up.

My next step is to reboot the computer on lockup...
login to windows automatically (easily done)...
Start program up via startup menu (easily done)... 
Enter login information, click Load (This is where i need "something")
Click "Start" again (another screen)

The "program" is a macro'enabled word document template. It has locked parts that I don't have access too. When it starts up it asks for login/pass/location. I need to enter that, click load, click start. I assume the program is in Word 2007, VB & Macro's.

So "something" that senses the box with Logon, Location, password fields... I know that kind of software is out there, but for the life of me I can't find the right terms to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is great for this. It has functions that will start a program, wait for a window to appear, enter text in fields and then simulate mouse clicks for the ok button. It was built for this type of use.

Comment: Wow... I think I just fell in love with a program...